# How to use JavaScript in Adobe AIR to get HTML content of a page?

Tags: javascript, html, air, cross-domain

I'm developing an Adobe Air app using JavaScript. I want to get HTML content of another website page, but I can't do it.

Requirement: cross-domain and no server.

Example: get HTML content of page "www.google.com" using JavaScript, which runs locally, no server.

Thanks for your help.:)

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Adobe AIR, but a quick google search of "adobe air api" lead me to [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/URLRequest.html).

It suggests that Adobe AIR is not restricted by the same security limitations as browsers when it comes to the same-domain policy.

Comment: oh,It seems to be a good solution,thank you very much~!

Answer (score 0):

No local server = no luck. You cannot make xmlhttp requests across domains from a browser. You need to do this from a server.

Comment: eh,thanks.I will try to find a way,thanks for your help.:)